# Selenium - can I disable javascript only for several urls?

Tags: python, firefox, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I need to disable javascript only for several urls, i.e.:

```
browser.get('http://mydomain.com/page1')
# some actions with JS off
browser.get('http://mydomain.com/page2')
# some actions with JS on
browser.get('http://mydomain.com/page3')
# some actions with JS on
browser.get('http://mydomain.com/page4')
# some actions with JS off
```

I know that I can pass firefox profile to `webdriver.Firefox()` with JS off, but this will apply for all pages. And I think that creating new `webdriver.Firefox()` instance for each page is not a good idea.

What the best way to solve this problem? TIA!

Comment: Do you need to enable/disable javascript within a single test? Or do you have different tests for each url?

Answer (score 0):

Split your tests into two big groups. One group runs all tests with JS disabled and the other group runs with JS enabled.

That way, you pay the initial setup cost only twice (instead of once per test).

Alternatively, you could organize your JS in such a way that everything goes through a global symbol (jQuery uses `$`).

Now you need two implementations of your framework. One is the normal implementation and the other is a mock/no-op implementation that simply doesn't do anything when functions of it are called.

You can then use `browser.executeScript()` to assign one of the implementations to the global symbol.

There are a couple of downsides, though:

1. Not all your frameworks will play along with this scheme
2. You will probably have to rewrite a lot of existing code to make this work
3. If you attach scripts to DOM nodes, then might continue to work as before if they keep references to internal things.

So I suggest to try the "two groups" approach :-)